# getting missing signature key while pulling mysql image usnig docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am successfully able to deploy and test `spring boot` application using `docker-compose` in local environment. But when I try the same in production environment, `docker-compose` is not able to pull `mysql` image.

It is running perfectly fine in local docker environment. But not executing in production.

Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysqldb:
   image: mysql:8
   container_name: mysqldb
   ports:
    - "3309:3306"
   environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: shopee
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
   volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/mysql 
  myapp:
   container_name: myeapp
   image: myapp:latest
   volumes:
    - /C/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 8.5/webapps/ROOT:/opt/    
   build: .
   ports:
    - 9898:9898
   depends_on:
    - mysqldb
   restart: always
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY myapp.jar /app/myapp.jar
EXPOSE 9898
CMD ["java","-jar","myapp.jar"]
```

on production server with `docker` and `docker-compose` environment set, it is giving below error when I execute `docker-compose up --build`

```
[+] Running 1/1
 ✘ mysqldb Error                                                                                                                                                                                                                        3.8s
Error response from daemon: missing signature key
```

My local environment is `Windows`

*yes I will change the tomcat volume accordingly*

My production environment is `Ubuntu`

why is it not able to pull `mysql` image and creating a `container` like it always did in local environment.

**UPDATE**

I should rather ask this way :

Not able to pull any image. Getting `Error response from daemon: missing signature key` in production server.

tried with `docker pull mysql`

Comment: I even tried `docker login` but no success. same response i.e. `missing signature key`

Comment: did you solve this? it seems it might be related to docker version maybe?

Answer (score 1):

seems like docker was not installed properly.
Remove docker using

```
sudo yum remove docker \
              docker-client \
              docker-client-latest \
              docker-common \
              docker-latest \
              docker-latest-logrotate \
              docker-logrotate \
              docker-engine
```

and the update os utils and add docker's repo using

```
sudo yum install -y yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

and the reinstall docker

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```